# Virtual World Plaforms and Unity3d

Tags: unity, mmo

I'm moving in the direction metaverse developing. A few years back I wandered around in Second Life and found it entertaining for a New York minute. Now, I'm set to plunge into the Virtual World/MMO enviroment. ReactionGrid's Jibe seems to be wonderfully paired with Unity3d. I've been a Unity developer for 5-6 years now. Is there a open source Virtual World Platform that integrates with Unity like Jibe? I've read an article on platforms like OGRE, Open Colbalt, OpenSimulator, Project Wonderland and Sirikata but none seem to mention working with Unity3d.

Comment: OGRE 3D is just a graphics rendering engine. But really powerful one.

Comment: Interesting! Just don't forget that for games you'd probably be better off creating your own server so that you can (correctly) handle all the security.